# MySQL: List and like?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I want to compare the value of a column with several list and print something else in each case. Its a list of car brands, like Chevy, Ford and so on. My logic should be like this:

```
if(mycolumn like carlist1, 'this', '')
if(mycolumn like carlist2, 'that', '')
if(mycolumn like carlist3, 'foobar', '')
```

mycolumn has a value like `Chevy-1234`, so it must be a like since the numbers will change. How could I do that in MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: post your table schema , some sample data and desired output with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to store the car list as a table, with data like:

```
Chevy
Ford
```

and so on.

Then you can do what you want with a join:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when cl.brand = 'Chevy' then 'this' end) as Chevy,
       max(case when cl.brand = 'Ford' then 'this' end) as Ford,
       . . .
from t left outer join
     carlist cl
     on left(t.col, length(cl.brand)) = cl.brand
group by t.id
```

Otherwise, you have to deal with the number:

```
select (case when left(col, locate('-', col) - 1) = carlist1 then 'this' end),
       (case when left(col, locate('-', col) - 1) = carlist2 then 'that' end),
       (case when left(col, locate('-', col) - 1) = carlist3 then 'foobar' end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in mysql like this

```
SELECT
  if(mycolumn like 'carlist1%', 'this', '') as 'Blah1',
  if(mycolumn like 'carlist1%', 'that', '') as 'Blah2',
  if(mycolumn like 'carlist1%', 'foobar', '') as 'Blah3'
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
SELECT
  WHEN mycolumn LIKE 'carlist1%' THEN 'this' END AS Blah1,
  WHEN mycolumn LIKE 'carlist1%' THEN 'that' END AS Blah2,
  WHEN mycolumn LIKE 'carlist1%' THEN 'foobar' END AS Blah3
FROM mytable
```